# Move recommended badge item under the badge progress

Tags: feature-request, design, badges, badge-progress

There is "Recommended" item in "Select your next badge" popup:

> [image: Move recommended]

My suggestion is to move that item below the badge progress bar (or even after the badge description). This will align all progresses horizontally for the left and right columns.
E.g.:

> [image: In the result]

Next **tag** badge popup looks even uglier:

> [image: Next tag badge]

Comment: ... or keep Recommended where it is and add space above the right column progress bar to keep the 2 columns aligned.  That would keep the Recommended word to be more prominently displayed.